# List of workbook VBA functions?

Tags: excel, vba

I have managed to get a list of the sheets and macros of a workbook using VBA Extensibility:

```
 For Each oComp In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
      Debug.Print oComp.Name
    Next oComp
```

Is there a way to get a list of the functions declared within the module and even better, a list of functions referred to within the code/the code itself?

Eventually this is to open other workbooks and list their functions/dependent functions.

Comment: @K_B i would not be so sure about that - you can basically parse VBA code with VBA, so I would say, it is possible to do this. But don't ask be how-excactly right now :) In case this is relevant due to documentation, doxygen is able to handle VBA, and quite well too after some modifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure now that you indeed can, sorry for my previous comment.

See http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx , please also take the warning in to account.

Good luck

Comment: especially section Exporting A VBComponent Code Module To A Text File should be useful for you